# Can't traceroute on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, traceroute

I have a kali VM running inside Virtual Box.

Traceroute does not work, the immediate resolution of host to IP works, but every hop fails until it reaches max hops. This happens for any host.

[image]

[image]

My VM runs in bridged network mode, I have switched to NAT and the same issue happens. Traceroutes from the host windows box work fine which rules out firewalls.

If i use nmap with a --traceroute flag that works fine

[image]
[image]

Traceroute version is 2.1.0 on Kali 4.8.0

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why Traceroute is not working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your network is blocking ICMP traffic.  Try using `traceroute -T` to use TCP rather than ICMP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, using the -Tflag with traceroute works correctly. Why though is it not blocked when I traceroute from the Windows host, if this happens at network level, I would expect both to experience the same issue. I assume this a VM oddity?

Comment: @iain Windows tracert uses ICMP. Linux traceroute uses UDP by default.